# How to make radial-background go outside a div?

Tags: html, css, background

I am stuck on a problem that i cant solve by myself, so i hope this post will help me a little bit.

I´m gonna explain it to you, if you dont understand what i ask, check my link to jsfiddle and i think it will be clear what my problem is.

I have a simple div, and i want to have a "radial-gradient" background in that, it should be focused in the middle and blurred out on the sides, but now i is cut of at the edges of the div, can i "bypass" that in some way?

http://jsfiddle.net/0e1k4zLj/ In that link, you can see that the faded blue is cut when it comes to the edges of the div.

```
<div class="empty"></div>

.empty {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-top: 25%;
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(30,87,153,1) 10%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%);
```

}

Comment: Try to make the DIV wider, or change the 100% at the end of the `background: ...` to 80% or so.